# Materialize grid with different image heights

Tags: html, css, grid, materialize, responsive-images

I'm using a materialize grid and dynamically adding records from my database but the problem is the accompanying images can be different heights as they are set to be responsive so that the records all appear with the same width. Initially the records in each row all align at the top but I want them to align at the bottom. Also when I collapse the screen down to tablet size, gaps appear beside some of the records.
I tried to fix the alignment problem by applying the following styles to the row and columns:

```
.row-format {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.minifig-container {
    padding: 2rem !important;
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align:bottom !important;
    text-align:center !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

This killed the responsiveness of the site completely because of the float: none style so I applied that only to the large screens so now on the large and small screens, the records are aligned at the bottom and there's no gaps but I still have a problem with the medium size screens that they're not aligned at the bottom and there still appears gaps beside some of the records.

So my question basically is: how to style these rows and columns so that records with different heights appear in the grid aligned at the bottom and also respond in the same way with different screen sizes without any gaps appearing in the grid?

Below is the HTML for to display the records.

```
<section class="max-width">
  <div class="row row-format">
    {% for minifigure in minifigures %} 
    {% if loop.index0 % 4 == 0 and loop.index0 != 0 %}
  </div>
  <div class="row row-format">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="minifig-container col s12 m6 l3">
      <ul class="collapsible popout">
        <li class="list-container">
          <img src="{{ url_for('file', filename=minifigure.photo) }}" class="photo responsive-img"/>
          <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons iconadd">expand_more</i><i class="material-icons iconremove">expand_less</i>
            <strong>{{minifigure.minifigure_name.title()}}</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="list-item">
              <strong>Theme:</strong>
              <span class="right">{{minifigure.theme_name}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
              <strong>Age:</strong>
              <span class="right">{{minifigure.age_range}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
              <strong>Feature:</strong>
              <span class="right">{{minifigure.feature.capitalize()}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
              <strong>Parts:</strong>
              <span class="right">{{minifigure.number_of_parts}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
              <strong>Rarity:</strong>
              <span class="right">{{minifigure.rarity_name}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
              <strong>Uploaded by:</strong>
              <span class="right">{{minifigure.uploaded_by}}</span>
            </div>
            <a class="edit-link"
              href="{{ url_for('edit_minifig', minifigure_id=minifigure._id) }}">
              <div class="edit list-item">Edit Minifigure<i class="material-icons chevron_right">chevron_right</i>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a class="edit-link"
              onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this minifig? It will be removed and no longer visible to other users??')) commentDelete(1); return false"
              href="{{ url_for('delete_minifig', minifigure_id=minifigure._id) }}"><div class="edit list-item">
                Delete Minifigure<i class="material-icons chevron_right">chevron_right</i></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="row row-height">
        <div class="right">
          <span>1</span><a href="{{ url_for('like_minifig', minifigure_id=minifigure._id) }}"><i onclick="likeMinifig(this)" class="fas fa-heart love-icon"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see this in action to help - can you prepare a fiddle?

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for getting back to me. I've never prepared a fiddle before. I'll have a look and see if I can figure it out. Do you just use https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Actually I prefer Codepen. But you can use whatever, the inbuilt Stack Overflow one is fine. In any case...they're very good for sorting problems out..so get used to them quick! :D

Comment: But this is an age old problem, with a ton of workarounds/solutions for various scenarios. Need to see your exact use case.

Comment: Try masonry grid